# Strange property of the functional equation $f(x+y)=ax+by$.

Tags: functions, functional-equations, change-of-variable, symmetric-functions, mixing-variables

Suppose
$$\tag{*}
f(x+y)=ax+by
$$
holds for some function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Given the function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$
g(x,y)=f(x+y)
$$
we see that it is symmetric with respect to $x,y$, since $x+y=y+x$. Then, it follows that
$$
ax+by=f(x+y)=g(x,y)=g(y,x)=f(y+x)=ay+bx
$$
and thus $a=b$. Hence, if $a\neq b$, (*) does not hold for any function $f$. Is this correct? In some sense, symmetry imposed by $g(x,y)=f(x+y)$ is extended to $ax+by$.

Comment: Just note that $f(0+0)=f(1-1)$ to get $a=b$ quickly.

Comment: And, from that, $f(x)=ax$ is the unique solution follows easily.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Set $y=0$ and see that $f(x)=ax$.